# How to modify JSON response body with mitmproxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, mitmproxy

When I send a request to a specific website API I get this as response

```
{
  "Tickets": [
    {
      "ticketAvailable": true,
...
```

How would I intercept and change `ticketAvailable` to `false` instead of `true` using mitmproxy?

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
from mitmproxy import http
import json

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url == "https://example.com/api/v1/something":
        data = json.loads(flow.response.get_text())
        data["data"]["Tickets"]["ticketAvailable"] = false
        flow.response.text = json.dumps(data)
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Have not managed to fix it yet

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
from mitmproxy import http
import json

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url == "https://example.com/api/v1/something":
        data = json.loads(flow.response.get_text())
        data["Tickets"][0]["ticketAvailable"] = "false"
        flow.response.text = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a way to fix it.
I simply changed `flow.request.pretty_url` to `flow.request.pretty_url.endswith`

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
from mitmproxy import http
import json

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url.endswith("/something"):
        data = json.loads(flow.response.get_text())
        data["Tickets"][0]["ticketAvailable"] = False
        flow.response.text = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tickets` is an array, so you'll need to access the 0th index in the array to update `ticketAvailable` to false. Also, there doesn't appear to be a `data` key in the response body, so there is no need for `["data"]` when navigating the dictionary's keys.

Also note that booleans in Python are capitalised, i.e., `True` and `False`, so you should either use the native Python boolean (useful if you actually need to use `data` elsewhere) or wrap `false` in quotes (fine if you are just loading `data` back into JSON, which it looks like you are).

Either:

```py
data["Tickets"][0]["ticketAvailable"] = False
```

Or:

```py
data["Tickets"][0]["ticketAvailable"] = "false"
```

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed everything you've said, but it still doesn't  work. I've posted my new code in an edit. I can see the script is successfully loaded into mitmproxy, but it's not doing anything as far as I can see.

Comment: How are you checking the update step? Have you tried printing `data` before and after updating? What do you see?

Comment: I managed to find a way to fix it.
Check my answer above.
Thank you so much for your help!